# MySQL trigger that checks data in two tables, then adds into other table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to right a trigger that will match offers and requests in a database, and if they match add the data into a different table. This is getting pretty complicated for me and maybe someone can point me in the right direction.
Here's what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER rideMatch
AFTER INSERT ON rideRequest
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT * from rideOffer r
    where r.time = new.time AND
    r.date = new.date AND
    r.pickUpLocation = new.pickUpLocation AND
    r.dropOffLocation = new.dropOffLocation
    )
 THEN
    INSERT INTO Ride(rideDate, pickUpTime, pickUpLocation, dropOffLocation, driver, carName)
    VALUES(new.date, new.time, new.pickUpLocation, new.dropOffLocation, r.driver, r.carName);
    END IF;
```

Comment: You are missing at least the `END` keyword. But since this is a single-statement-trigger, you can just remove the `BEGIN` keyword.

Comment: What is the problem with this query?

Comment: I should've been more clear. I also want to delete the entries from the original tables when this happens. It also gives me some syntax errors at the end and I'm not sure if I can reference the r table in the final insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think this type of logic should be done in a trigger.  It seems like application logic, not data integrity.  A stored procedure seems like a more apt place.

That said, you need to get data from the offers table.  I think something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER rideMatch
AFTER INSERT ON rideRequest
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  insert into Ride(rideDate, pickUpTime, pickUpLocation, dropOffLocation, driver, carName)
    select new.date, new.time, new.pickUpLocation, new.dropOffLocation,
           r.driver, r.carName
    from rideOffer r
    where r.time = new.time AND
          r.date = new.date AND
          r.pickUpLocation = new.pickUpLocation AND
          r.dropOffLocation = new.dropOffLocation
    limit 1;
end;
```

Notes:

- This will choose an arbitrary matching `rideOffer`.
- If nothing matches, nothing is inserted.
- This logic is not correct, at a minimum because the same `rideOffer` could end up used for multiple requests.
- You really should be using the primary key from `rideOffer` rather than putting in the values of fields.

In other words, this should answer your question.  However, I think there are major flaws with the application design -- flaws that are much outside the scope of this question.